# How to prevent autorotate for UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, autorotate

I'm working on an application with supporting portrait and landscape modes based on constraints. When a UIAlertView is popping up, the autorotate feature causing a weird effect. I want to avoid autorotation of UIAlertView only. Please help me

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Searched and tried different solutions, but didnt work at all. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think you can enable landscape support and not have alert views automatically adjust. you may just have to implement a custom `UIView` to do this

Answer (score 1):

if You declaring AlertView in other class.. in your case AppDelegate

**AppDelegate.h**

```
 @property BOOL alertShowing;
```

**AppDelegate.m**
when you call show alertview set a bool as alertview showing.

```
 UIAlertView *YOUR_ALERTVIEW = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:details delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Okay", nil];
 self.alertShowing = YES; //SET A BOOL PROPERTY UNIVERSALLY
 [YOUR_ALERTVIEW show];
```

set bool back to NO after dismiss of alertview

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
   self.alertShowing = NO;
  }
```

**ViewController.m**

then check this bool before auto rotate.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

   BOOL rotate;
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   if (appDelegate.alertShowing) {
    if (appDelegate.alertShowing==YES) {
        rotate = NO;
    }
    else if(appDelegate.alertShowing == NO)
    {
        rotate = YES;
    }

   }
   else
   {
    rotate = YES;
   }
   return rotate;
}
```

Comment: Actually alertview is displaying from a viewcontroller where i have disabled autorotate. But the function for display of alertview is defined in appdelegate (sharedApplication Delegate). As required, this method is called. Will this one work on this scenario???

Comment: if you are calling alertview in appDelegate set the BOOL in appDelegate. and check the appDelegate.alertviewShowing ==true

Comment: Check whether-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate is calling

Comment: just check the bool value?

Comment: Everything is fine... except autorotate prevention.. :(

Comment: Is there anything to do with :

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

Comment: you dont need to call  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: